# Correct way to return values using MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

What is the correct way of returning JSON data via API controller in MVC4? I've heard that you need to use variable type as function, however I cannot do that because I can't use `.Select(x => new { })` then.

What I do instead is to use `dynamic` like so

```
[HttpGet]
public dynamic List() // Not List<Item>
{
    var items = _db.Items.OrderBy(x => x.ID).Select(x => new
    {
        ID = x.ID,
        Title = x.Title,
        Price = x.Price,
        Category = new {
            ID = x.Category.ID,
            Name = x.Category.Name
        }
    });

    return items;
}
```

Is this best way of doing this? I'm askin' because I just started with MVC4 and I don't want to pick up bad habits early :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `dynamic`, the simple way is to return `object` for anonymous type:

```
[HttpGet] 
public object List() // Not List<Item> 
{ 
    var items = _db.Items.OrderBy(x => x.ID).Select(x => new 
    { 
        ID = x.ID, 
        Title = x.Title, 
        Price = x.Price, 
        Category = new { 
            ID = x.Category.ID, 
            Name = x.Category.Name 
        } 
    }); 

    return items; 
}
```

Or, return `HttpResponseMessage`:

```
[HttpGet] 
public HttpResponseMessage List() // Not List<Item> 
{ 
    var items = _db.Items.OrderBy(x => x.ID).Select(x => new 
    { 
        ID = x.ID, 
        Title = x.Title, 
        Price = x.Price, 
        Category = new { 
            ID = x.Category.ID, 
            Name = x.Category.Name 
        } 
    }); 

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, items);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Built-in function `Controller.Json` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)) can do what you want, i.e. assuming your code resides inside controller class:

```
[HttpGet]
public dynamic List() // Not List<Item>
{
    var items = _db.Items.OrderBy(x => x.ID).Select(x => new
    {
        ID = x.ID,
        Title = x.Title,
        Price = x.Price,
        Category = new {
            ID = x.Category.ID,
            Name = x.Category.Name
        }
    });

    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If you want to use it in GET requests, then you should use overload which accepts `JsonRequestBehavior` flags as parameter and specify `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` for that parameter.